# Print content of file from desired character and end also to desired character

Tags: text-processing

I have this file with content written below.

I want output of my file stating with `".SUBCKT C032_THS_COMPARATOR" and end with ".ENDS"`:

```
.SUBCKT C032_THS_DPDNPROT_cdm_tdpdnw TOPROTECT VPLUS
.SUBCKT C032_THS_DPDNPROT_cdm_tdndsx TOPROTECT VMINUS
*
************************************************************************
* Library Name: DUMMY
* Cell Name:    
* View Name:    schematic

.SUBCKT C032_THS_COMPARATOR  DGND DVDD Icomp PDANAN 
+ VOUT VP
*.PININFO CH:I CHN:I Icomp:I PDANA:I PDBANA:I VN:I VP:I VOUT:O AGND:B AVDD:B 
*.PININFO DGND:B DVDD:B
MP9 net11 CHN D1 AVDD egpfet m=1 w=2.5u l=0.2u nf=1.0 pccrit=0 plorient=1 
+ ngcon=1 p_la=0 ptwell=0 swacc=0 swrg=-1 swrsub=-1 nqs=0 mismatch=1
MP3 net044 net029 DVDD DVDD egpfet m=1 w=4u l=0.15u nf=1.0 pccrit=0 plorient=1 
+ ngcon=1 p_la=0 ptwell=0 swacc=0 swrg=-1 swrsub=-1 nqs=0 mismatch=1
MP1 V V V V egpfet m=2 w=3u l=0.5u nf=1.0 pccrit=0 plorient=1 ngcon=1 
+ p_la=0 ptwell=0 swacc=0 swrg=-1 swrsub=-1 nqs=0 mismatch=1
MP0 net11 D1 AVDD AVDD egpfet m=1 w=3u l=2u nf=1.0 pccrit=0 plorient=1 ngcon=1 
+ p_la=0 ptwell=0 swacc=0 swrg=-1 swrsub=-1 nqs=0 mismatch=1
MP2 net7 D1 AVDD AVDD egpfet m=1 w=3u l=2u nf=1.0 pccrit=0 plorient=1 ngcon=1 
+ p_la
1 
+ ngcon=1 p_la=0 ptwell=0 swacc=0 swrg=-1 swrsub=-1 nqs=0 mismatch=1
MN4 net7 c TAIL AGND egnfet m=2 w=8u l=1u nf=1.0 pccrit=0 plorient=1 ngcon=1 
+ p_la=0 ptwell=0 swacc=0 swrg=-1 swrsub=-1 nqs=0 mismatch=1
.ENDS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/\.SUBCKT C032_THS_COMPARATOR/{p=1};p;/\.ENDS/{p=0}' file
```

**Explanation**

- If we see `.SUBCKT C032_THS_COMPARATOR`, set `p = 1`.
- If we see `.ENDS`, set `p = 0`.
- Depending on `p` value, we can track current position is inside or outside range, If in, `p` is `1`, meaning true in boolean context, causing `awk` default action to print the whole input line. If out, `p` is `0`, meaning false in boolean context, `awk` do nothing.

or `sed`:

```
sed -e '/\.SUBCKT C032_THS_COMPARATOR/,/\.ENDs/!d' file
```

Comment: or `awk '/\.SUBCKT C032_THS_COMPARATOR/,/\.ENDs/' file`

Comment: @Jidder: Yes, but mine can be more flexible since when you can omit any side if you want.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: also you dont need those `;` it could be written as `awk '/\.SUBCKT C032_THS_COMPARATOR/{p=1}/\.ENDs/{p=0}p`

Comment: @Jidder: I mean if you want include or exclude start or end. Your `awk` will omit the last line

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working fine can you please bit explain to make me learn how this is working ...

Comment: But op doesn't, and you haven't posted any alternative and the code you have posted works identically to mine. Any code CAN be more flexible, you still have to change it though.

Comment: @yisha: I updated my answer with explanation.

Comment: @Jidder, POSIX requires the semicolon.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No it doesn't

Comment: @Jidder, [it may not for long](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226) but it still does.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I cant see anything on that page which says not using a `;` would make my comment/awk statement above invalid. Can you point me to the relevant part please ?

Comment: @Jidder, see the grammar there. I should know. I raised that issue. And apparently the outcome seems to be to continue disallowing it (even though all modern implementations I know of allow it). See how there has to be a "terminator" after each "item" (and the end of the script is considered as a "terminator" in the description).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I remember that you have mentioned this issue in another post.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Does the --posix option for awk not actually run the code as though it were posix awk then ? Also i tried it on my posix system and it worked so i'm not sure what version of awk you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
sed -n '/\.SUBCKT\ C032_THS_COMPARATOR/,/\.ENDS/p' filename
```

HTH, Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Another sed:

```
sed '1,/^$/d;/\.ENDS/q'
```

Though - just judging by the data provided, it maybe the `.ENDS` address is unnecessary.

I suppose you could also do:

```
sed '/^\..*COMPARATOR/,/^\./!d'
```

Comment: Tricky for this case only, as the OP question, I think he want the start and the end mark for general case.

Comment: @Gnouc - of course it is for this case. What else would it do? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: As the title said **from desired character and end also to desired character**.

Comment: @Gnouc - I know, and then they provided the goods. I don't work on imagination - I'm not imaginative enough. I just try to do what works with what's before me.